# Renderizar componente de Qwik de manera dinámica

Tags: jsx, qwik

Estoy agrupando varios componentes de la siguiente manera.

```
import Top_v1 from "./v1/top";
import Top_v2 from "./v2/top";

export default {
    v1: Top_v1,
    v2: Top_v2,
}
```

La idea es que según la configuración se pueda renderizar un componente u otro.

Si lo hago así: `<Header.v2/>` funciona muy bien. Pero necesito ingresar el "v1" o "v2" de manera dinámica según un string que recibo.

Esto no saca error pero no muestra nada:

```
{ Header["v2"] }
```

Esto saca error:

```
<Header["v2"]/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera.

```
import { component$, Slot } from "@builder.io/qwik";

import Header from "../components/layout/top/top";


export default component$(() => {

  const MyHeader = Header["v2"]

  return (
    <>

      <MyHeader/>
      <main>
        <Slot />
      </main>
    </>
  );
});
```

No puedo renderizar un componente de la forma `<Header[version] />` porque no se le puede poner una expresión.

Entonces la solución es colocar la expresión aparte:

```
const MyHeader = Header["v2"]
```

Y luego llamarla asi:

```
<MyHeader/>
```